# Matlab - Initialize a script in every two seconds

Tags: matlab, animation

I tried to write an animation code in Matlab that repeats itself in every two seconds. The core animation scheme is as below:

[image: GIF image for Core animation]

Please take care the gif is repeating the core animation, originally there is only one cycle.

Here is the code:

```
    % Figure settings
h= figure(2);
set(h, 'Position', [100 50 1200 750])
set(h,'Toolbar','None','Menubar','None')
set(h,'Name','Animation')
set(gcf,'doublebuffer','off');
set(gca, 'xlimmode','manual','ylimmode','manual','zlimmode','manual',...
         'climmode','manual','alimmode','manual');
xlim([-200 1350])
ylim([-250 800])
set(gca,'xtick',[],'ytick', [], 'Position', [0 0 1 1]);

%Parameters
diameter = 60; %spot çapı
RamanX = 350; %ölçüm noktssı x konumu
nOfSpots = 4; %spot sayısı
spotCount = 0; %toplam spot sayısı
initPos = [50 150;50 300; 50 450; 50 600]; %konum 1
posII = [350 150;350 300; 350 450; 350 600]; %konum 2
Choice = rand(1,4)<.5; %Ölçüm sonunda verilen karar
deltaY2 = 100; % spotlar arası mesafe


x11 = zeros(nOfSpots,2);
x22 = zeros(nOfSpots,2);
x22a = zeros(nOfSpots,2);
x22b = zeros(nOfSpots,2);

for i=1:nOfSpots
    x11(i,:) = [RamanX   150*(i-1)];
    x22(i,:) = [800 50+deltaY2*(i-1)];
end

for i=1:nOfSpots/2
    x22a(2*i-1,:) = [1280 -270+250*(i-1)];
    x22a(2*i,:) = [1075 -270+250*(i-1)];
    x22b(2*i-1,:) = [1280 220+250*(i-1)];
    x22b(2*i,:) = [1075 220+250*(i-1)];
end

%Add 4 Circles to initial position
for i=1:nOfSpots
    % Drag & Drop elipsler yerleştiriliyor
    spot(i) =  imellipse(gca, [initPos(i,1),initPos(i,2),diameter,diameter]);
    spotCount = spotCount+1;
    %elips özellikleri
    setFixedAspectRatioMode(spot(spotCount), 'TRUE');
    setResizable(spot(spotCount),0);
    posSpot(spotCount,:) = getPosition(spot(i));
end

%Move Circles to posII
r = sqrt(sum(bsxfun(@minus,posII(:,1),initPos(:,1)).^2,2));
v = 30;
stepsize = ceil(r/v);
xstep = (posII(:,1)-initPos(:,1))/stepsize;

for i=1:stepsize
    for j=1:nOfSpots
        setPosition(spot(j), [initPos(j,1)+xstep(j)*i, initPos(j,2), diameter, diameter] )
        posSpot(spotCount,:) = getPosition(spot(j));
    end
    pause(0.15)    
end

%Move Circles to posIII

velocity = 30;
r2a =  sqrt(sum(bsxfun(@minus,x22a,x11).^2,2));    
stepsize2a = max(ceil(r2a/velocity));
r2b =  sqrt(sum(bsxfun(@minus,x22a,x11).^2,2));    
stepsize2b = max(ceil(r2b/velocity));
% Eğer öllçüm seçimi 1 ise taşı
for i=1:nOfSpots
    if(Choice(i))
        xstep2(i) = (x22a(i,1)-x11(i,1))./stepsize2a;
        ystep2(i) = (x22a(i,2)-x11(i,2))./stepsize2a;
    else
        xstep2(i) = (x22b(i,1)-x11(i,1))./stepsize2b;
        ystep2(i) = (x22b(i,2)-x11(i,2))./stepsize2b;
    end
end
stepsize2 = max([stepsize2a stepsize2b]);

% Eğer ölçüm seçimi 0 ise taşı
for i=1:stepsize2
    for j=1:nOfSpots
        if(Choice(j))
            setPosition(spot(j), [posII(j,1)+xstep2(j)*i, posII(j,2)+ystep2(j)*i, diameter, diameter] )
            posSpot(spotCount,:) = getPosition(spot(j));
        end
    end
    pause(0.15)
end

for i=1:stepsize2
    for j=1:nOfSpots
        if(~Choice(j))
            setPosition(spot(j), [posII(j,1)+xstep2(j)*i, posII(j,2)+ystep2(j)*i, diameter, diameter] )
            posSpot(spotCount,:) = getPosition(spot(j));
        end
    end
    pause(0.15)
end

if(spotCount > 0)
    for i=1:4
        delete(spot(i))
    end
end
```

The code doing this is a script not a function, say "animation.m". Now I am trying repeat this code in every 2 seconds. I tried to use loops with tic - toc commands, but the loop does not go to other cycle before finishing "animation.m". I need to get it work in the background.

One of my friend suggested me to use trigger. But, honestly, I could not apply the trigger command for my code even when I functionalized it.

Any help?

Edit:
The graphical flow chart of the problem is below:

[image: The graphical flow chart of the problem]

Comment: Recommendation: Implement a function that perform just one animated step (each time you execute the function, it "renders" a single frame). Then you can use a timer to execute a step every 2 seconds. You can also try Parallel Computing Toolbox.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I created an example that shows how it could be done.
Modifying your code, to draw just "one animated step" was too much work.
I decided to used your code to create all frames from advance (for example purpose).
I guess you are going to realize, that implementing background animation in Matlab is more difficult than you thought (unless I missed some hidden Matlab feature).
Matlab has very limited threading support, so I used a periodic timer.

My code sample does the following:

- Build animation - create a cell array of all animated images.
  *You should avoid it, because it takes to much time (and memory).*
  I used it instead of modifying your code to draw one animated image.
- Setup a periodic timer object with 0.2 seconds period (0.2 as an example).
- I added a loop that illustrates the foreground processing (calculating sin(x) as an example).
  Notice: I added small pause in the "foreground processing" loop.
- The timer invokes a callback function every 0.2 seconds.
  In the callback function the next animated frame is shown.
  The timer is used for simulating a background execution.
  You should replace the `imshow`, with your "animation step" function, that draws the frame (instead of showing a frame created from advance).

---

Here is the code sample (with your modified code included):

```
function TimerAnimation()

    %Build set of images for animation.
    [h_figure, Frames] = BuildAnimation();

    t = timer;
    t.TimerFcn = @timerFcn_Callback; %Set timer callback function
    t.ExecutionMode = 'fixedRate';   %Set mode to "singleShot" - execute TimerFcn only once.
    t.StartDelay = 0.1;              %Wait 0.1 second from start(t) to executing timerFcn_Callback.
    t.Period = 0.2;                  %Set period to 0.2 seconds.

    %Turn on figure visibility
    set(h_figure, 'Visible', 'on');
    frame_counter = 1;

    start(t) %Start timer;

    %Do some other job...
    %The animation is executed in the background (kind of in the background).
    for x = 1:20000
        y = sin(x/10000); %Calculate somthing...
        if (mod(x, 100) == 0)
            disp(['sin(', num2str(x/10000), ') = ', num2str(y)]); %Display somthing...
        end

        if (~isvalid(h_figure))
            %Break loop if user closed the animation figure.
            break;
        end

        %Must insert pause to "tight loop", allowing animation to run.
        pause(0.01);
    end

    stop(t)     %Stop timer;
    delete(t);  %Delete timer object.
    if (~isvalid(h_figure))
        close(h_figure);
    end


    %Timer function is executed every period of 0.2 seconds.
    function timerFcn_Callback(mTimer, ~)
        %Increse animation frame counter.
        %figure(h_figure); %Set fo h_figure to be active figure.

        h_axes = get(h_figure, 'CurrentAxes'); %Get axes of h_figure
        imshow(Frames{frame_counter}, 'Parent', h_axes); %Display frame number frame_counter.
        drawnow; %Force refresh.
        frame_counter = mod(frame_counter, length(Frames)) + 1; %Advance to next frame (cyclically).
    end
end


function [h, Frames] = BuildAnimation()
%Build set of images for animation.
%h - return handle to figure
%Frames - return cell array of animation images.

counter = 1;

% Figure settings
%h = figure(2);

%Create invisible figure.
h = figure('Visible', 'off');

set(h, 'Position', [100 50 1200 750])
set(h,'Toolbar','None','Menubar','None')
set(h,'Name','Animation')
set(gcf,'doublebuffer','off');
set(gca, 'xlimmode','manual','ylimmode','manual','zlimmode','manual',...
         'climmode','manual','alimmode','manual');
xlim([-200 1350])
ylim([-250 800])
set(gca,'xtick',[],'ytick', [], 'Position', [0 0 1 1]);

%Parameters
diameter = 60; %spot ?ap?
RamanX = 350; %?l??m noktss? x konumu
nOfSpots = 4; %spot say?s?
spotCount = 0; %toplam spot say?s?
initPos = [50 150;50 300; 50 450; 50 600]; %konum 1
posII = [350 150;350 300; 350 450; 350 600]; %konum 2
Choice = rand(1,4)<.5; %?l??m sonunda verilen karar
deltaY2 = 100; % spotlar aras? mesafe


x11 = zeros(nOfSpots,2);
x22 = zeros(nOfSpots,2);
x22a = zeros(nOfSpots,2);
x22b = zeros(nOfSpots,2);

for i=1:nOfSpots
    x11(i,:) = [RamanX   150*(i-1)];
    x22(i,:) = [800 50+deltaY2*(i-1)];
end

for i=1:nOfSpots/2
    x22a(2*i-1,:) = [1280 -270+250*(i-1)];
    x22a(2*i,:) = [1075 -270+250*(i-1)];
    x22b(2*i-1,:) = [1280 220+250*(i-1)];
    x22b(2*i,:) = [1075 220+250*(i-1)];
end

%Add 4 Circles to initial position
for i=1:nOfSpots
    % Drag & Drop elipsler yerle?tiriliyor
    spot(i) =  imellipse(gca, [initPos(i,1),initPos(i,2),diameter,diameter]);
    spotCount = spotCount+1;
    %elips ?zellikleri
    setFixedAspectRatioMode(spot(spotCount), 'TRUE');
    setResizable(spot(spotCount),0);
    posSpot(spotCount,:) = getPosition(spot(i));
end

%Move Circles to posII
r = sqrt(sum(bsxfun(@minus,posII(:,1),initPos(:,1)).^2,2));
v = 30;
stepsize = ceil(r/v);
xstep = (posII(:,1)-initPos(:,1))/stepsize;

for i=1:stepsize
    for j=1:nOfSpots
        setPosition(spot(j), [initPos(j,1)+xstep(j)*i, initPos(j,2), diameter, diameter] )
        posSpot(spotCount,:) = getPosition(spot(j));
    end
    %pause(0.15)

    %Get frame, convert frame to image, and store image in Frames
    Frames{counter} = frame2im(getframe(h));counter = counter + 1;
end

%Move Circles to posIII

velocity = 30;
r2a =  sqrt(sum(bsxfun(@minus,x22a,x11).^2,2));    
stepsize2a = max(ceil(r2a/velocity));
r2b =  sqrt(sum(bsxfun(@minus,x22a,x11).^2,2));    
stepsize2b = max(ceil(r2b/velocity));
% E?er ?ll??m se?imi 1 ise ta??
for i=1:nOfSpots
    if(Choice(i))
        xstep2(i) = (x22a(i,1)-x11(i,1))./stepsize2a;
        ystep2(i) = (x22a(i,2)-x11(i,2))./stepsize2a;
    else
        xstep2(i) = (x22b(i,1)-x11(i,1))./stepsize2b;
        ystep2(i) = (x22b(i,2)-x11(i,2))./stepsize2b;
    end
end
stepsize2 = max([stepsize2a stepsize2b]);

% E?er ?l??m se?imi 0 ise ta??
for i=1:stepsize2
    for j=1:nOfSpots
        if(Choice(j))
            setPosition(spot(j), [posII(j,1)+xstep2(j)*i, posII(j,2)+ystep2(j)*i, diameter, diameter] )
            posSpot(spotCount,:) = getPosition(spot(j));
        end
    end
%   pause(0.15)

    %Get frame, convert frame to image, and store image in Frames
    Frames{counter} = frame2im(getframe(h));counter = counter + 1;
end

for i=1:stepsize2
    for j=1:nOfSpots
        if(~Choice(j))
            setPosition(spot(j), [posII(j,1)+xstep2(j)*i, posII(j,2)+ystep2(j)*i, diameter, diameter] )
            posSpot(spotCount,:) = getPosition(spot(j));
        end
    end

%   pause(0.15)
    %Get frame, convert frame to image, and store image in Frames
    Frames{counter} = frame2im(getframe(h));counter = counter + 1;
end

if(spotCount > 0)
    for i=1:4
        delete(spot(i))
    end
end

imshow(Frames{1})
end
```

---

Example for what I meant by **"drawing just one animated step"**:

```
function TimerAnimation2()
    %Initiazlie animation.
    param = InitAnimation();

    %Same code as in previous example.
    t = timer;t.TimerFcn = @timerFcn_Callback;t.ExecutionMode = 'fixedRate';t.StartDelay = 0.1;t.Period = 0.2;start(t)
    for x = 1:20000;if (~isvalid(param.h)), break;end;pause(0.01);end 
    stop(t);delete(t);if (isvalid(param.h)), close(param.h);end

    %Timer function is executed every period of 0.2 seconds.
    function timerFcn_Callback(mTimer, ~)
        %Animation single step
        param = StepAnimation(param);
    end
end


function param = InitAnimation()
    h = figure;

    set(h, 'Position', [100 50 1200 750]);set(h,'Toolbar','None','Menubar','None');set(h,'Name','Animation');set(gcf,'doublebuffer','off');
    set(gca, 'xlimmode','manual','ylimmode','manual','zlimmode','manual', 'climmode','manual','alimmode','manual');
    xlim([-200 1350]);ylim([-250 800]);set(gca,'xtick',[],'ytick', [], 'Position', [0 0 1 1]);

    %Initialize param struct (param struct keeps animation parameters). 
    param.h = h;
    param.x = 10;
    param.y = 10;

    %Draw rectangle in position x, y
    h_axes = get(param.h, 'CurrentAxes');
    rectangle('Position', [param.x param.y 20 20], 'Parent', h_axes);
end


%Example fo single animation step
%Get exsiting animation param as input, and retuen updated param as output.
function param = StepAnimation(param)
    h_axes = get(param.h, 'CurrentAxes');

    %Update param (to be used in next StepAnimation).
    param.x = param.x + 10;
    param.y = param.y + 10;

    if (param.x > 500), param.x = 10;end
    if (param.y > 500), param.y = 10;end

    %Draw rectangle in position x, y
    rectangle('Position', [param.x param.y 20 20], 'Parent', h_axes)
    drawnow; %Force refresh.
end
```

Comment: That's really hard work Rotem, thanks. What should I do to repeat only the animation code in every 2 seconds.  I edited the question with a graphic that describes what I want. Perhaps that would be more clear. The idea of frame by frame programming is nice but than I need calculate a huge number of frames since we don't know when the user wants to stop the animation.

Comment: I didn't mean you need to "calculate a huge number of frames". I instructed you to replace it by **"drawing just one animated step"**. I added an example showing what I meant by **"drawing just one animated step"**.